# Strange IE rendering for select multi dropdown after clicking input type text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, select

In IE if I select input type text and after I go and select one option from the select drop down list the width of the select box gets bigger.But if I select first time the drop down list than the width of the select box will be displayed normally. I don't understand why the select multidropdown width gets bigger after you focus your mouse on the input box. Can someone help me sort it out?

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="tbl">
    <div class="cell">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name herve..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <label>Options</label>
        <select class="">
          <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

.tbl {
  display: inline;
  width: 600px;
 }
.cell {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 50%;
}
input, select, textarea{
display: block;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
input {
padding: 0 5px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
}
select {
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6jyffjuo/)

Comment: The same effect is noticeable even if all of your custom formatting is removed from the fiddle. Looks like a browser bug.

Comment: Any existing workaround for this kind of IE bug?

Comment: Dunno, first time I’m seeing it. Try researching if other people have come across something similar, maybe check the official Edge bug/issue tracker (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/)

Comment: 2019 and i bumped into the same problem.